# jQuery hide(); and show(); issue in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been wrestling with Internet Explorer for a few hours now and can't seem to figure out my problem. I'm trying to achieve a simple "group option switcher" with jQuery show() and hide().

It's probably best if you look at my demo to see what I mean: http://softwaredb.org/test/jquery-multi-select.html

My code works in every browser except IE. My code is this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Demo - Jquery Multi Select box</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  select{width:200px;height:200px;}
  select#boysnames, select#girlsnames{display:none;}
  </style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper" style="padding:50px 0 0 50px;">

<form>      
    <select multiple="multiple" id="theoptions">
        <option value="boysnames">Boys Names</option>
        <option value="girlsnames">Girls Names</option>
    </select>

    <select multiple="multiple" id="placeholder">
    </select>

    <select multiple="multiple" id="boysnames">
        <option>John</option>
        <option>David</option>
        <option>Tom</option>
    </select>

    <select multiple="multiple" id="girlsnames">
        <option>Jenny</option>
        <option>Amanda</option>
        <option>Sara</option>
    </select>
</form>
</div> <!-- end #wrapper -->

<script type="text/javascript">
$('option[value="boysnames"]').click(function() {
    $('select#placeholder, select#girlsnames').hide();
    $('select#boysnames').show();
});
$('option[value="girlsnames"]').click(function() {
    $('select#placeholder, select#boysnames').hide();
    $('select#girlsnames').show();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My logic is... on click, hide all other select tags and show the one I'd like to see. It seems to work fine, until I try in IE. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I'm very new to jquery (and javascript/programming in general) so forgive me if this is a dumb question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of tracking clicks on the option level, track a change on the select level.

```
$('select#theoptions').change(function() {
    $('#placeholder, #girlsnames').hide();
    if($(this).val() == 'boysnames') {
        $('#boysnames').show();
    } else {    
        $('#girlsnames').show();
    }
});
```

There are many ways to make your approach a little more intuitive, but this should get you going on the path that you're on

Comment: You were doing the some same code for true and false. So I just placed it outside.

Comment: worked! You are the man! I'm going to select your reply as the answer in 4 minutes (when it lets me). Thanks dude!

Comment: No problem! I just wanted to also show you how I might approach this problem if I started it from scratch, hopefully you can take something away from it :) http://pastebin.com/eFG3Kg8W

Comment: Awesome! Your code is much cleaner than mine. The project I'm working on has tons of options in the select boxes, which means lots of code with my approach. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#theoptions').click(function() {
    if($(this).attr('value') == "boysnames")
    {
        $('select#placeholder, select#girlsnames').hide();
        $('select#boysnames').show();
    }
    if($(this).attr('value') == "girlsnames")
    {
        $('select#placeholder, select#boysnames').hide();
        $('select#girlsnames').show();
    }

    });

    </script>
```

use this ..